# Hello, invoking restwebservice from bpel?

Tags: web-services

I am trying to invoke mapquest geocoding api from BPEL by passing variables as city, state to get response as latitude and longitude accordingly. But its showing error

fault 1:

> oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: Unable to invoke
>   endpoint URI
>   "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=XXXXXXXXXXX"
>   successfully due to: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Bad response: 403
>   Forbidden from url
>   http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=XXXXXXXX?City=xxxx&County=xxxx&State=xxxx&Zip=xxxx&operationName=Request-Response

Comment: Please add your code to the question so the community can review it and possibly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be "&" after key=XXXXXXXX instead of "?".

[http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=XXXXXXXX&City=xxxx&County=xxxx&State=xxxx&Zip=xxxx&operationName=Request-Response](http://%20http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=XXXXXXXX&City=xxxx&County=xxxx&State=xxxx&Zip=xxxx&operationName=Request-Response)